# Android Studio Editor Bug

Tags: android, ide

recently I upgraded to windows 10 and after the upgrade I started having some problems with Android Studio can't find JDK, SDK etc. I reinstalled and did all of the configuration (showing JDK and SDK paths) and everything ran OK, but afterwards my editor font colors were not displayed correctly (member variables, method names, class names etc.). I tried everything from changing the theme to invalidating cache and deleting the workspace file. If someone could help me out with this I will be very grateful. I uploaded a screenshot just in case.

[image]

Comment: Just to add some more information, everything works fine, it is just the fonts and colors that are acting up.

Answer (score 0):

So I found what the problem was, Power Save Mode was activated, to deactivate it,  go File > Power Save Mode.
Cheers